# OSMC boots to scrolling sad face

Tags: boot, osmc

Following an update freeze, I disconnected my Pi 3 and now just get a scrolling sad-face: anyone got a re-boot recipe?

Comment: Welcome. *"Just get a scrolling sad-face"* -> First I've heard of that one.  You might want to describe this in more detail, as it sounds a little out of the ordinary.

Comment: Soz - thought it might mean something… Well, on powering up, I first of all get a black screen, with script that flashes too fast to read, blue screen with the OSMC symbol, black (void) followed by blue screen with the ‘sad face’ symbol alternating… but with no further progress

Comment: OSMC -- okay that makes sense then.  Usually best to try and provide as much relevant info as you can, eg., which OS you are using... I've changed the title to better focus on the details of the problem.

Comment: You’re a gent/gal! Ta